# Find function recursively Binary Tree

Tags: java, search, recursion, binary-tree

I have a bit of problem doing this function:
`public boolean find(Integer i)`

At first I tried:

```
public boolean find(Integer i) {
    Node currNode = root;

    if (currNode.getData() != i) {
        return false; // we didnt find it
    }
    if (currNode.getLeft() != null && find(currNode.getLeft().getData())) {
        return true;
    }
    if (currNode.getRight() != null && find(currNode.getRight().getData())) {
        return true;
    }
    else 
        return false;
}
```

But this is only giving me `false` in my test case. I was wondering how to find a specific data in the binary tree and return `true` if the input data is found within the binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, I'm guessing this is more like what you want:

```
public boolean find(Integer i) {

    if (getData().intValue() == i.intValue()) {
        return true; // we found it
    }

    if (getLeft() != null && getLeft().find(i)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (getRight() != null && getRight().find(i)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If not, provide more of your solution code to help guide a better answer.